# why do i need to take an int minus a char to get correct result? c#

Tags: c#

I have a line in my function that calculates the sum of two digits.

I get the sum with this syntax:

```
sum += get2DigitSum((acctNumber[0] - '0')  * 2);
```

which multiplys the number on index 0 with 2.

```
public static int get2DigitSum(int num)
    {
    return (num / 10) + (num % 10);
```

Lets say we have number 9 on index 0. If i have `acctNumber[0] - '0'` it passes the `9` into the other function.But if I don't have the `- '0'` after the `acctNumber[0]` it passes `12`. I don't understand why I get wrong result if I don't use `- '0'`.

Comment: Because you are passing ASCII characters, not numbers from `acctNumber`. What is `acctNumber`? A string?

Comment: please create a [MCVE]

Comment: @RonBeyer acctNumber is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are providing `acctNumber[0]` to `get2DigitSum`.

`get2DigitSum` accepts an integer, but `acctNumber[0]` is not an integer, it holds an `char` which represents a character with an integer value.

Therefore, you need to subtract the '0' to get the integer.
'0' to '9' have ASCII values of 48 to 57.

When you subtract two `char` values, actually there ASCII values get subtracted. That's why, you need to subtract '0'

Comment: thanks for the answer. i thought i was passing an integer but I did pass a string.. lol

Comment: @teslagosu You meant that you passed a `char` (UTF-16 code unit), not a string. `acctNumber` is a `String`. `acctNumber[0]` is a `char`.

Answer (score 4):

The text "0" and the number 0 are not at all equal to a computer.

The character '0' has in fact the ASCII number 48 (or 0x30 in hex), so to convert the character '0' into the number 0 you need to subtract 48 - in C and most languages based on it, this can be written as subtracting the character '0', which has the numerical value 48.

The beauty is, that the character '1' has the ASCII number 49, so subtracting the number 48 (or the character '0') gives 49-48=1 and so on.

So the important part is: Computers are not only sensitve to data (patterns of bits in some part of the machine), but also to the interpretation of this data - in your case interpreting it as a text and interpreting ist as a number is not the same, but gives a difference of 48, which you need to get rid of by a subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

Internally all Characters are represented as numbers. Numbers that then get converted into nice pictograms during display only.

Now the digits 0-9 are [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) codes 48-57. Basically they are offset by +48. Past 57 you find the english alphabet in small and then large. And before that various operators and even a bunch of unprintable characters.

Normally you would not be doing this kind of math at all. You would feed the whole string into a Parse() or TryParse() function and then work with the parsed numbers. There are a few cases where you would not do that and isntead go for "math with Characters":

- you did not know about Parse and integers when you made it
- you want to support arbitary sized numbers in your calculations. This is a common beginner approach (the proper way is BigInteger).
- You might be doing stuff like sorting mixed letter/number strings by the fully interpreted number (so 01 would come before 10). The same way windows sorts files with numbers in them.
- You do not have a prewritten parse function. Like I did back when I started learning in C++ back in 2000.