# LINQ with Lambda. Aggregate

Tags: c#, aggregate

Why here result is 50 but not 2?

`int n = 2; n = n.ToString().Aggregate(1, (a, b) => a * b)`

But here is 2?

```
int n = 2; n = n.ToString().Aggregate(1, (a, b) => a * (b -'0'))
```

How's it work?

Comment: For the second code snippet, I got 2 instead of 4. Did you read the output wrong?

Comment: You're aware that `b - '0'` is equal to `b - 48`, right? And yes, the result of the second code snippet is 2, not 4.

Comment: sorry, my misstake. Why in first test it was 50 but second is 2?

Comment: Because `a * b == 1 * b == 1 * 50` and `b - '0' == b - 48 == 50 - 48`. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why do i need to take an int minus a char to get correct result? c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921459/why-do-i-need-to-take-an-int-minus-a-char-to-get-correct-result-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both sample `a` is an `int` and `b` is a `char`.

`a` is your seed, = 1, and `b` is the unicode value of '2', = 50. Hence the result in the first case is 50.

The unicode value of '0' is 48, so the result is 2.